# Condition with Swing Options

Tags: java, swing, loops, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

I get `NullPointerException` when I press the CANCEL Option in my Swing.

Code:

```
while(!input.equals(CANCEL_OPTION));
```

And I get a  message that it says incompatible types....

And here's my full code..

```
do
    {
    input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String.");


    for(int i =input.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {           
        result = result + (input.charAt(i));
        disp.append("\n").append(result);
    }       

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,input+"\n"+disp+"\n"+"\n"+result);
    input="";
    disp.setLength(0);
    result="";
    }
    while(!input.equals(CANCEL_OPTION));
```

And the error code or something..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Reverse.main(Reverse.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use try catch statement..

```
try
    {
    do
    {
        //your codesss......
    }
    while(!input.equals(null));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     ////code..
    }
```

hope it help.

Comment: But if `input` is `null` then invoking the `equals` method on it will throw a `NullPointerException` and if it is NOT `null` the result will always be false. So what is the benefit of such a condition?

Answer (score 5):

As the javadoc of [JOptionPane.showInputDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) states

> Returns user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

if you want the user to enter something.

```
do {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String.");
} while (input == null); // user can't cancel

for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = result + (input.charAt(i));
    disp.append("\n").append(result);
}

....
```

Comment: +1 but not required any loop, simple If - if else - else

Answer (score 0):

Swap your `do while` for a simple `while`. The difference is, a `do while` will run once, before it hits the test condition. Your code is receiving the `CANCEL_OPTION` value which is `null`, attempting to use it, *then* testing if it is `null`. You need to move your test to the start.

**Example**

```
input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String.");

while(input != null) {
    // Your code here.
}
```

***NOTE***: This will give the user the option to cancel should they wish to. If they do, it will skip processing the user input.

Comment: I hate mornings. Thank you for being sharper than me!

Comment: That's fine.. `input==null` returns a boolean.

Comment: I might as well just apply for Mcdonald's now.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the cancel button the JOptionPane returns nothing, so your input is equal null. and you code will already enter the do scoop, and when your code reach the line :

```
for(int i =input.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
```

the input is already null.

i prefer to add after the that line the follwing:

```
if(input == null) {
            break;
        }
```